# Water pressure drops while any faucet turned on

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, shower

My incoming pressure gauge read 85psi from meter. My outgoing pressure after pressure reducer is 55psi. When using shower it decreases to about 45 psi. But incoming from still reads steady 85psi. Is this normal?  It’s a zurn Wilkins 70xldu.

Comment: Is that pressure reducer rated for a particular flow rate?

Comment: I don’t know what flow rate it is.

Comment: I looked up the specs on your PRV, and it seems to be a good one with plenty of flow.  We get people that ended up with totally wrong products sometimes, so have to ask the basics.

Comment: @JPhi1618 so you think it’s simply some sand in the internal prv?

Answer (score 0):

Turn the pressure up after the PRV to 75 psi and see how it behaves. The PRV may have an inlet screen/strainer that needs cleaned. The downstream pressure should remain fairly steady with flow until the capacity of the PRV is exceeded or the inlet pressure falls.

Comment: Ok. I turned the prv to 60 psi and when in use it drops to 50 psi. It could be dirt in the screen inside the prv. Is there a way to clean the internal cartridge without buying one? The repair kit from Home Depot is around $75 and the brand new prv is around $85.

Comment: Take the PRV out of the line or remove enough of the inlet line to see the screen, which should be right at the inlet. If it is dirty you will need to clean it. You also said that the down stream pressure fell from 60 to 50; did the inlet pressure fall also or remain steady?